# upload and downloading to ftp using python

Tags: python, ftp

First am a newbie learning python . Am trying to upload/download a file to a server using python . the server ftp has no domain name but an IP address i.e. 192.168.0.20 and the port 21
I tried the following code but it is giving a lot of errors

```
import ftplib

#FTP server credentials
FTP_HOST = '192.16.0.20'
PORT='21'
FTP_USER = 'ftpuser'
FTP_PASS = 'ftpuser'

# connecting to the FTP server
ftp = ftplib.FTP(FTP_HOST,PORT, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS)
# force UTF-8 encoding
ftp.encoding = "utf-8"
# local file name you want to upload
filename = "test.txt"
with open(filename, "rb") as file:
# use FTP's STOR command to upload the file
    ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {filename}', file)
# list current files & directories
ftp.dir()
# quit and close the connection
ftp.quit()
```

help- where am i going wrong

Comment: *"it is giving a lot of errors"* does not give us any information about the errors you are getting. We need exact errors you get getting.

Comment: Can you specify how those errors look like?

Comment: File "C:\Users\Josiah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ftplib.py", line 252, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 530 User cannot log in.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to login to the server using `ftp.login()`after your creation of the `FTP` object.

Which exact errors do you get?

Comment: How do i do this in my code ? an example please

Comment: OP already logs in by `ftplib.FTP(FTP_HOST,PORT, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS)`

Comment: The example in the [documetation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) requires additional login call.

Comment: It does not matter if you login by passing credentials to the constructor or by using the `login` method. It's the same.

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right. I did not check the documentation of that constructor. @OP which exact errors do you get?

Comment: File "C:\Users\Josiah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ftplib.py", line 252, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 530 User cannot log in.

Comment: `530 User cannot login` indicates (as it says) a fault of your ftp server or that particular account. Which ftp server are you trying to connect to?

Comment: hello I can connect to myserver using Winscp, Filezilla or any other client put  only in passive mode How do i do these in the code above ?